# Erro JavaScript quando confirma alteração de pequenas alterações

Tags: bug, status-pronto

[image: screenshot]

Fiz uma pequena correção, apenas uma letra.
HTML% editei para HTML5.

Clico em "salvar" e aparece um aviso para confirmar se realmente desejo salvar algo com baixa quantidade de modificações. Então clico em "salvar" novamente e o processo parece nunca terminar.

No console do Chrome, o erro JS. Vide o screenshot.

O mesmo aconteceu num outro post que não lembro mais qual é, há uns 3 dias.

Comment: Parece uma questão para o StackExchange https://media.giphy.com/media/EaMTsoYxfPpuw/giphy.gif

Answer (score 4):

Fixed in next build (rev `2015.2.12.2293`).